# Getting an error "Module not found: Can't resolve './User.scss' " when running heroku-postbuild

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass

I am writing a chat using React/Redux/Firebase

I have next structure:

```
components
 User
  index.js
  User.scss
  UserHeader.js
  UserItem.js
  UserList.js
  UserSerach.js
 Message
  index.js
  Message.scss
  MessageList.js
  ...
```

All styles of components of "type" User are located in the file User.scss
I'm not sure what's right. I don't like a lot of folders with components

My actions:

```
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
heroku create
heroku git:remote -a project-name
git push heroku master
```

In the file package.json i also write:

```
"engines": {
    "npm": "6.4.1",
    "node": "10.14.2"
}
```

And to start production after installing packages:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run serve"
```

During heroku package installation I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/User/UserHeader.js
remote:        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './User.scss' in '/tmp/build_0467563cc44feeb52e4f8bb96c6f75fa/src/components/User'
remote:         @ ./src/components/User/UserHeader.js 3:0-33 8:15-21 10:15-21 14:15-21 16:15-21 19:15-21
remote:         @ ./src/components/User/index.js
remote:         @ ./src/components/Chat/Chat.js
remote:         @ ./src/components/Chat/index.js
remote:         @ ./src/components/App/App.js
remote:         @ ./src/components/App/index.js
remote:         @ ./src/index.js
```

But I imported the User.scss:

```
import styles from './User.scss';
```

The same error pops out for other User components. But I have same structure with one scss file in Message components and there are no errors..

Styles in the webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
              '>1%',
              'last 4 versions',
              'Firefox ESR',
              'not ie < 9'
            ],
            flexbox: 'no-2009'
          })
        ]
      }
    },
  'sass-loader'
  ]
}
```

I have already tried several other style settings - the same error.

### Edit

I found out that the error was in the scss file name (user.scss => User.scss). But I'm getting the same error.

I had a mistake that I fixed after reading that the webpack or the Windows console or the Heroku (I don't remember) caches files. And when you change their location or the names for the Heroku they don't change. Something was like that but I don't remember.

I need to enter something in the console so that changes to files and paths are taken into account. Maybe someone knows?

### Edit 2

Solved my stupid problem:

1. Made a commit on the GitHub by changing the name of the files to the correct ones. It's not working if I change files locally, because of the problem that I wrote above)
2. Made a git pull
3. Now the Heroku works :)

But I still want to know how to solve the problem written above.

Comment: does it work if you require it? something like `const styles = require('./User.scss');`

Comment: No, the same error